# saving german numbers

Tags: asp.net, globalization

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and a view which is bound to the model. I use globalize.js for globalization and I also have extended jQuery validation, like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) ||
                !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
            range: function (value, element, param) {
                //Use the Globalization plugin to parse the value        
                var val = $.global.parseFloat(value);
                return this.optional(element) || (
                    val >= param[0] && val <= param[1]);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

so the view works fine with German numbers using "." as group-seperator and "," as comma-seperator.

My problem is, when I save the view by submitting the form, the controller action is called and the ModelState is not valid because all numbers containing a group-seperator of "." are generating an error "The number its not a valid number". All numbers which have only a comma-seperator of "," are valid. The culture is set correct to "de-DE". Have I to do something special before saving?

Comment: Dumb question, but did you also set the `web.config` values? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: There is never a dumb question ;-) And yes, I set these values: <globalization uiCulture="de" culture="de-DE" />

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

I added a custom ModelBinder for double values referencing [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx), but it didn't work. After some further research I recognized, that "double" and "double?" are 2 different types and I had invoked the DoubleModelBinder only as  `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(double), new DoubleModelBinder());`in Global.asax.cs. So I added the line `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(double?), new DoubleModelBinder());` and now, all works fine with German separators.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN article [Supporting ASP.NET MVC 3 Validation with Non-English Locales](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674880%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

you may need to do below  changes

> In addition to including the localized methods script, you must make
>   sure that the current locale on the server is set to the target locale
>   so that any server-side messages (used for both client-side and
>   server-side validation) will be used correctly.
>
> Typically when a server is configured, the correct locale is selected as part of the
>   operating system installation. If the server is not set to the correct
>   locale, do the following:
>
> ```
> In the Windows Control Panel, open Regional and Language Options.
>
> Select the Location tab
>
> In the Current location list, select the target locale
> ```